# Multiple Origin Browser Tabs, Single Destination Tab

Tags: javascript

**Background**

I work on our internal tool that is a JS webapp. Users have asked if they can click a link and it open a new tab and every subsequent click of the link will load in the same tab that was opened (the link href changes). This isn't a problem. But the problem is the users that will open our app in multiple tabs and still want this link to load in the one tab.

For a single origin, single destination problem I do something like this:

```
let tab = null;

$scope.openLink = function() {
  if (tab && !tab.closed) {
    tab.location.href = 'http://duckduckgo.com';
    tab.focus();
  }
  else {
    tab = window.open('http://google.com','googlewindow');
  }
}
```

`<a href="" ng-click="openLink()">click me</a>`

**Problems**

I can't store the `tab` object in anything because of circular javascript object and cross domain security issues. I'm hoping there's a way to pare down the `tab` object so that it can be stored and used in other tabs with IndexedDB or even sending it to my DB (MSSQL).

**My Question**

Is there a way to store the information so I can set the location of the tab from any instance of my web app?

If not, is there any other solution that someone has done?

**Final Thoughts**

I've been pouring over this problem and it is probably pushing the limits of browser capabilities or security, but I've been asked to look into it so I'm here now.

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do, it is impossible from a web page (famous last words, someone will show it is possible) ... a WebExtension may be the way to go

Comment: I was anticipating that it was impossible to do. That's what it looked like from my findings

Comment: I may not understand clearly though

Comment: Basically Tab A opens links in Tab B. This works fine. Now they want Tab C to also open links in Tab B

Comment: yeah, that can't be done, except *maybe* via an extension

Comment: alright, thanks. Honestly I look forward to the exercise of writing an extension if the users want it